# Pick a marble from 3 buckets uniformly at random

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

The problem is as follows :

> I have three buckets with marbles. Each bucket has **k**, **l**, **m** marbles respectively (k + l + m = N)
>
> I will pick one marble from EACH of the three buckets with probability 1/k, 1/l, 1/m respectively and I'll put them into a another bucket.
>
> What I am looking for, is the probability that I should assign to each of the three marbles so that I get to choose one Uniformly at random (1/N).

(Since each marble came to the final bucket with a different probability i cannot just pick one with 1/3 probability - that won't be uniformly).

Sorry if the specification is a bit vague, I did my best to explain it.

Comment: Choose final three probabilities in inverse ratio to those from each bucket?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, we need to assign probabilities of choosing each of the three marbles from the "big" bucket (second bucket), such that the probabilities for choosing any marble from the original three is the same. In other words, the final marble that we choose should be equally likely to come from buckets $k,l$ or $m$.

Let's let $K$, $L$, and $M$ be the (so far unknown) probabilities of reaching into the big bucket and choosing a marble originally from bucket $k$, $l$, or $m$, respectively.

Then $$\frac{1}{k}K + \frac{1}{l}L + \frac{1}{m}M = 1$$
and $$\frac{1}{k}K = \frac{1}{l}L = \frac{1}{m}M = \frac{1}{3}$$

This is satisfied if we let
\begin{align*}
K&=\frac{k}{3} \\
L&= \frac{l}{3} \\
M&= \frac{m}{3}
\end{align*}